# Could I add the mapping from old instructions to new instructions to VMap when using CloneFunctionInto()?

Tags: llvm

I run into a problem when changing the parameter type and return type of a function. I do it in the following way:

1. Create a new function type with new return type and new parameter type
2. Map old parameters to new parameters with new type, and add the mapping to `VMap`
3. For each old instruction in the function body which requires a new type, I create a new instruction with new type, and add the mapping to VMap
4. Using `ClondFunctionInto(new_fun, old_fun, VMap, true, Returns)` to copy the body of the old function to the new function, with all values in the `VMap` replaced with its new version.

Then I got the following error:

```
/llvm/lib/Transforms/Utils/ValueMapper.cpp:444: void llvm::RemapInstruction(llvm::Instruction*, llvm::ValueToValueMapTy&, llvm::RemapFlags, llvm::ValueMapTypeRemapper*, llvm::ValueMaterializer*): Assertion `(Flags & RF_IgnoreMissingEntries) && "Referenced value not in value map!"' failed.
```

Is Step 3 correct?  Since the document of `CloneFunctionInto()` said "Clone OldFunc into NewFunc, transforming the old arguments into references to VMap values." Could I also transform the old instructions in the function body to new ones in the `VMap`?